# Inkscape extension, how to get a g element width and height?

Tags: python, inkscape

I know about:

```
node.get("wight")
```

or:

```
node.attrib("wight")
```

But for elements that don't have their attibute, like g element. How can I get the width?

Answer (score 1):

You can either use the Inkscape command line to get an exact width/height:

inkscape file.svg --query-width --query-id

(The returned value is in px (SVG user units),
see https://inkscape.org/en/doc/inkscape-man.html#OPTIONS )

Or you can use the (imperfect) convenience functions provided by the file simpletransform.py that can be found in Inkscape's extension directory, i.e. computeBBox() .